# sorl.thumbnail does not work?

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I installed sorl.thumbnail through pip and manually through GitHub but it doesn't work, I've added `'sorl.thumbnail',` to the INSTALLED_APPS (I also tried adding the project name infront of it, it yields a no module named error).

I've uninstalled and reinstalled countless times, it shows up in virtualenv when I do `lssitepackages` but it doesn't import in the Django shell, nor in the code. I'm not sure what to do or how to fix this.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named sorl.thumbnails
```

I'm also using Django Multiuploader (https://github.com/garmoncheg/django_multiuploader) if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are importing `sorl.thumbnails` instead of `sorl.thumbnail`, which gives you the error. Use `sorl.thumbnail` should likely fix your problem.